Render a list of jsx components in react
I have a list, containing some jsx components like components:
components = [
  <span className="c1 c2" onClick={() => console.log("test")}>...</span>,
  <span className="c1 c2" onClick={() => console.log("test")}>...</span>,
  <span className="c1 c2" onClick={() => console.log("test")}>...</span>,
]

BTW the components, is made with pushing into array:
for(...) {
  components.push(<span ...>...</span>)
}

and i use this list as below:
const MyList = () => {
  return (
    <p>{components}</p>
  )
}

the problem is that, after rendering, items don't have any onClick (or onclick event handler) function.
although they have class property, and the event is set to function noop() {}.
Browsers inspector shows them like:
// there is no 'onclick' function
<span class="c1 c2">...</span>
...

New problem:
Suppose that c2 class is like:
.c2{
  color: blue;
}
.c2:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

It changes color of text to blue, but it doesn't show pointer on hover(doesn't do anything on hover), too.
I appreciate any help.

There is no problem creating an array of elements with onClick. When the elements are rendered, the click handlers will work properly.
In the demo below, click each letter to see the corresponding handler respond. For more info about the key property, read Rendering Lists -


const components = [
  <span
    className="c1 c2"
    children="A"
    key="A"
    onClick={() => console.log("test A")} />,
  <span
    className="c1 c2"
    children="B"
    key="B"
    onClick={() => console.log("test B")} />,
  <span
    className="c1 c2"
    children="C"
    key="C"
    onClick={() => console.log("test C")} />,
]

const MyList = () => {
  return (
    <p>{components}</p>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<MyList />)
p { display: flex; flex-direction: row; gap: 1rem; }
span { display: block; padding: 0.5rem; background-color: #fc0; }
span:hover { opacity: 0.8; }
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>




Still your code works.
The following code - a copy of yours - works for me. Please see the console logs enclosed below.
App.js
export default function App() {
  let components = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    components.push(
      <span className="c1 c2" onClick={() => console.log('test: ' + i)}>
        ...
      </span>
    );
  }
  return <p>{components}</p>;
}

Test run
Console logs generated on clicking three of each content.

The reason for seeing function noop() {} for each of the handler can be found here react onclick function loading as "function noop() {}"
Note: The new problem may also be looked if it is still relevant for you. You may please comment

Hey @WeDoTheBest4You, you're right, I found problem with one of my css classes, i don't know how but when i remove it the code works fine. I will explain it in an answer.

Event handlers like onClick only work when elements are created and rendered within React's rendering process (as in the "render" in class components). If you create and store JSX elements in an array outside the component's lifecycle (like in your example), React won't properly attach event handlers to those elements.
You should do this instead


const MyList = () => {
  // Define different functions
  const handleClick1 = () => console.log("Clicked item 1");
  const handleClick2 = () => console.log("Clicked item 2");
  const handleClick3 = () => console.log("Clicked item 3");

  // Array of data and corresponding event handlers
  const items = [
    { text: "Item 1", onClick: handleClick1 },
    { text: "Item 2", onClick: handleClick2 },
    { text: "Item 3", onClick: handleClick3 },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <span
          key={index}
          className="c1 c2"
          onClick={item.onClick} // Assign specific onClick handler
        >
          {item.text}
        </span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyList;



The case above assumes that your components are rendering only span tags. If they were dynamic, say you want to render a div, a button and a p tag, I would do this instead - create the array to have objects with the elementType and props


import React from "react";

const DynamicComponents = () => {
  const components = [
    {
      elementType: "div",
      props: {
        className: "box",
        onClick: () => console.log("Div clicked"),
        children: "I am a Div",
      },
    },
    {
      elementType: "button",
      props: {
        className: "btn",
        onClick: () => console.log("Button clicked"),
        children: "Click Me",
      },
    },
    {
      elementType: "p",
      props: {
        className: "text",
        onClick: () => console.log("Paragraph clicked"),
        children: "I am a Paragraph",
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {components.map((component, index) => {
        const { elementType, props } = component;
        const Element = elementType; // React allows you to use a string to represent an element type dynamically
        return <Element key={index} {...props} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DynamicComponents;




I tested answers, same results. In fact, there is no problem with my code or answers, let's see how it solved.
The structure of MyList component is as follow:
return (
  ...
  // the problem is one of style classes of my <p>
  <p className="c3 c4">
    // components contains some <span className="c1 c2">...</span>
    {components}
  </p>
  ...
)

And the c4 class is exactly:
.c4 {
  float: right;
}

I don't know how but when i remove this class from <p> it works fine.
The problem solved, and thanks for all the replies.

Hi, As you know, float : right will push the element to the right of the screen.

Yes i really know, believe me when i remove that class from list of classes it works fine, and there is a problem with float property in my code. I removed the c4 class and added the float attribute to another class and the functionality broke again. and I don't know, HOW?
